# How to make an invisible (transparent/blank) app icon in Nova Launcher?

Tags: launcher, app-icons, nova-launcher, hidden, icon-packs

In Nova Launcher Prime 6.x, how does one make an app's icon invisible (completely transparent / blank)?

I can try to find (or create) an icon pack that contains a blank icon (preferably on F-Droid), but I'm hoping there is a faster solution.

Comment: Not clear. You want to make the icon of an existing (installed) app transparent? But still occupying space? What about its label? Should tapping it open the app?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Answers: Yes. Yes. No label (easy in Nova). Yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Took me a bit, but I figured it out:

1. Download and install Pocket Paint from F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.catrobat.paintroid/
2. Create a completely empty (and transparent) `.png` file, which is currently the default image for Pocket Paint.
3. Save the `.png` file.
4. In Nova Launcher Prime, long press the desired app, click `Edit`, and then click the existing icon.
5. In Nova Launcher Prime, select `Gallery apps`.
6. Select the image saved in step 3.
7. Voilà!

Comment: I followed those instructions. But when I try to apply the picture it just makes the whole folder black. I'm at a loss.